# retrieving core data into tableview cells swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, tableview, xcode6.1

I am trying to simply store and retrieve CoreData (something that I've done successfully before with swift). I was getting a nil for data, but now (not sure what changed) I'm not getting an error, just nothing showing in the tableview. I'm not sure if it's a problem in storing or retrieving the object. I've followed how I did it in another app of mine as closely as possible, but there seems to be some fundamental thing that I'm not getting. Here's what I have.

My model:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(DataModel)
class DataModel: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var itemName: String
@NSManaged var quantity: NSNumber
@NSManaged var price: NSNumber

}
```

In my tableviewcontroller with static cells for text fields that I want to save data from:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NewItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var itemNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var itemPriceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var itemQuantityTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //CoreData
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    var newItem = DataModel(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    newItem.itemName = itemNameTextField.text
    //newItem.price = itemPriceTextField.text
    //newItem.quantity = itemQuantityTextField
    managedContext.save(nil)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


}
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

And in my tableviewcontroller that I want to retrieve the data an show in dynamic cells:

```
class ItemListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var items : Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return items.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID: NSString = "cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell
    var data: NSManagedObject = items[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject


    var itemName = data.valueForKey("itemName") as String
    var price = data.valueForKey("price") as NSNumber
    var quantity = data.valueForKey("quantity") as NSNumber


    cell.textLabel!.text! = "\(itemName)"
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text! = "Price: \(price) - Quantity: \(quantity)"

    return cell

}
```

Any help on a concept I might have missed somewhere in here would be appreciated! Thanks.

Update: so I've redone my code to be modeled after @Bluehound 's suggestion. but I'm still getting an error: not sure how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: How and where is your `items` array populated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using core data and a tableview, you should use `NSFetchedResultsController`. This essentially retrieves data from core data and organizes it by section and indexPath so it can easily be set as the data source of the tableView. Here is a complete implementation of a potential UITableViewController that conforms to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData


class HomeViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: allEmployeesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)


    }

    func allEmployeesFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nameLast", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        return fetchRequest
    }

    //MARK: UITableView Data Source and Delegate Functions
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if let cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Employee {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cellContact.nameLast), \(cellContact.nameFirst)"

        }


        return cell
    }

    //MARK: NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Functions
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
        }

        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Employee)
            managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
        case .Insert:
            break
        case .None:
            break
        }

    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

[See a sample GitHub project here.](https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo)