# Save and load data to / from Core Data database (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

First of all I have to say that I am pretty new to iOS programming. I develop and Core Data App with Swift. I have a `UITableViewController`, called tanningarTableViewController" where I want the data to be displayed the data is going to be added (saved) in another ViewController called "nyTankning".

I have followed a tutorial on Youtube, but because Swift has changed during since the WWDC I have had to search for other sultans sometimes. 
I am not 100% sure The UITableViewController is coded right, but I guess, because it seems like the problem is with the saving?  I have read about some `NSFetchedController` or something like that, should I use that?

Here is the button I expect to save the data:

```
 @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Reference to out app delegate

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // Reference moc
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tankningslista", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)



    // Create instance of our data model and initialize 
    var nyTankning = Model(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map our properies
    nyTankning.liter = (textFieldLiter.text as NSString).floatValue
    nyTankning.kronor = (textFieldKronor.text as NSString).floatValue
    nyTankning.literpris = (textFieldLiterpris.text as NSString).floatValue


    // Save or context
    contxt.save(nil)

    println(nyTankning.liter)
    println(nyTankning.kronor)
    println(nyTankning.literpris)


    if contxt.save(nil) {

        // Fetch the Data from Core Data first....
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")
        var error:NSError?
        var result: NSArray = contxt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!


        for res in result {

            // Now you can display the data

            println(res.liter)
            println(res.kronor)
            println(res.literpris)

        }

        // End of the fetching

    } else {
         println("error")
    }

    // navigate back to root vc
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

And here is the code for the UITableViewController

```
   import UIKit
   import CoreData

   class tankningarTableViewController: UITableViewController {

       var Tankningar: Array<AnyObject> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let contxt:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")

    var error :NSError?

    let fetchedResults = contxt.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
    if let results = fetchedResults { Tankningar = results
    }
    else
    { 
     println("Could not fetch \(error)")   
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

    println(Tankningar)
    println("freq")
    println(freq)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return Tankningar.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...

    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"

    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")

    var data: NSManagedObject = Tankningar[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

    var literLabel = data.valueForKeyPath("liter") as? String
    var kronorLabel = data.valueForKeyPath("kronor") as? String
    var literprisLabel = data.valueForKeyPath("literpris") as? String

    cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("liter") as? String

    return cell
}
```

When I check the debugger it seems like the array that I created in the TableViewController is empty:

```
 []
freq
 <NSFetchRequest: 0x7ffd4ad24830> (entity: Tankningslista; predicate: ((null));     sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
34.0
551.0
14.0
39.0
551.0
14.0
[, ]
freq
<NSFetchRequest: 0x7ffd4ae8c330> (entity: Tankningslista; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

What is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27514083/3810673 this might help. It shows an implementation of an NSFetchedResultsController, which is better to use when linking Core Data to a UITableViewController

Comment: I will test that. What should I replace Eployee with? 

        if let cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Employee {

Comment: That is your ManagedObject Subclass. If you do not have a subclass either make one or use NSManagedObject (I suggest making one) this represents the object in core data that the cell essentially linked too