# (Swift) Edit saved data at indexPathFOrSelectedRow using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a UITableViewController and a ordinary ViewController. In the VC (named nyTankning) there the user will type in info that is saved to a Core Data database. The database is loaded and displayed in the UITableVieController.

Now I want to be able to edit the info that is saved in the database. I have searched for the answer, but I haven´t found anything helpful, because I have used NSFetchedResultsController after following [retrieving core data into tableview cells swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513689/retrieving-core-data-into-tableview-cells-swift/27514083#27514083)

Right now the code that I have wrote in the TableViewController looks like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "update" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let selectedCell = fetchedResultsController?.indexPathForObject(indexPath!) as? NSManagedObject
        let nyTankning: nyTankningViewController = segue.destinationViewController as nyTankningViewController

        nyTankning.liter = selectedCell?.valueForKey("liter") as String
        nyTankning.kronor = selectedCell?.valueForKey("kronor") as String
        nyTankning.exisitingTankning = selectedCell


    }
```

But I understand from the Debugger that the indexPath is not written properly.

> 2015-01-16 17:14:22.207 TankApp[4232:241135] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c274660'

EDIT:Here is the full code for the whole UITableViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class tankningarTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var firstTime = 0

let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: allaTankningarFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)


}

func alertViewFirstTime() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "TankApp", message:
        "Du kan lägga till en ny tankning genom att trycka på plusknappen (+).", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func allaTankningarFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "datum", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.predicate = nil
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    return fetchRequest
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    if firstTime == 0 {
        alertViewFirstTime()
        firstTime++

    }
    else {
        return
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section. 
    return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
}


//MARK: NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Functions
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    }

    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Model)
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    case .Insert:
        break
    case .None:
        break
    }

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...

    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"

    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")

    if let cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Model {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cellContact.datum)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(cellContact.liter) Liter, \(cellContact.kronor) Kronor, \(cellContact.literpris) Kronor/Liter"

    }

    return cell
}
/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "update" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as nyTankningViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as Model)

        destination.event = indexPath != nil ? fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as? NSManagedObject : nil
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `objectAtIndexPath` instead of `indexPathForObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplish it like this using the ternary operator to handle the case for unwrapping the optional index path, but `if let` works just as well to avoid any crashes that may occur from that. Also, I would suggest using `indexPathForCell` and using `sender` as your cell rather than `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "SomeSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as SomeViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForCell(sender as SomeCell)

        destination.event = indexPath != nil ? fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as? NSManagedObject : nil
    }
}
```

With this method, you pass the entire managed object to the next view controller where you handle that accordingly. If you want to maintain setting all the destinations class variables from this method, you use `if let` to unwrap the optional index path like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "SomeSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as SomeViewController
        if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForCell(sender as SomeCell) {
            let object = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject
            destination.foo = object?.bar
        }
    }
}
```

[See a sample GitHub project here.](https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo)

Comment: Great, I will test that. SomeCell? What should I write there?

Comment: Whatever your UITableViewCell subclass is. If you aren't subclassing your cell just change it to UITableViewCell, and actually it shouldn't matter which one because a subclass inherits from UITableViewCell

Comment: /Users/manssandberg/Desktop/TankApp/TankApp/tankningarTableViewController.swift:204:34: '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathForCell'

Comment: Is your class a subclass of `UITableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`? and is your frc delegate set `fetchedResultsController.delegate = self`

Comment: class tankningarTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: allaTankningarFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)

Comment: What is in your `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section. 
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0

Comment: I use the above code in my project and it works so there must be something underlying wrong with your project, for a complete sample `UITableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27514083/3810673

Comment: It is the same link as mine in the question, right? I copy-pasted it, so what can be wrong?
[section] - should I replace that word?

Comment: Check the github link i just added to the answer

Comment: Check my Code in the first post. It is floatValues from UITextFields that I want to send. "Float is not convertible to String" How do I solve that?

Comment: "\(someFloat)" creates a string from a float

Comment: Hope this is last question. :P Where exactly should I put "(someFloat)"?

Comment: I meant:   "\\(someFloat)" and in the `prepareForSegue` you should set `destination.someStringVar = "\(someFloat)"`

Comment: Yes, it works! But I don´t understand why the value (it is putted into a UITextField) is: "Optional(theDataIWrote)

Comment: Because it is optional. Unwrap it using ! or the nil coalescing operator ??