# Fetching Data from TableView (CoreData)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I am building an app with Swift 3 and so far I have integrated the ability to store the user's location using CoreData and display them in a TableView. Now I want to retrieve each location data (if there is any and up to 20 locations) to continue working with that.

I have trouble doing that, could someone assist me?

Comment: Have you tried using `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: @TomHarrington I tried but I couldn't really manage

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513689/retrieving-core-data-into-tableview-cells-swift).

It helps.

When using core data and a tableview, you should use NSFetchedResultsController. This essentially retrieves data from core data and organizes it by section and indexPath so it can easily be set as the data source of the tableView.